# Upgrading Gradle from 7.4.2 to Gradle 8.0.0 gives error on release app - java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I have recently upgraded Android Studio to Flamingo and also upgraded Gradle from 7.4.2 to 8.0.0. All things working fine in version 7.4.2.

When I generate a signed APK using Gradle 8.0.0, it's giving me a runtime error of `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

I have tried many solutions like adding Proguard rules for Retrofit, Okio, OkHttp, etc., but it still give me an error like this.

Note: When I downgraded from 8.0.0 to 7.4.2, it's working.

So anyone can help me to find out problem with AGP 8.0.0.

***build.gradle(app)***

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}


android {
    
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 22
        versionName "1.0.16"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        /*vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }*/

        def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
        def localProperties = new Properties()
        localProperties.load(new FileInputStream(localPropertiesFile))
        buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", localProperties['API_KEY']



    }

    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
        viewBinding = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    
    implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:0.24.11-rc'
    implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-webview:0.24.11-rc'
    implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.24.13-rc'
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.24.13-rc"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-drawablepainter:0.25.1"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-flowlayout:0.31.0-alpha"


   
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material'
//    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-viewbinding"
    implementation project(path: ':pdfviewer')

  
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4"

    
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.45"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.45"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'

  
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.1"

  
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.6.1"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.6.1"

    /* *****************************************************
       **** Retrofit2
       ****************************************************** */
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0'

   
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'

   
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.1"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1"

    
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.1"

   
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1'

    
    def billing_version = "5.2.0"
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version"
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:$billing_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.9.5'

   
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.0.0'

   
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie-compose:4.0.0'


}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}
```

**Project Gradle File**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.5.0-alpha02'
        kotlin_version = '1.8.10'
    }
        dependencies {
            // Add this line
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
            classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.5'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace. There are a number of breaking changes in Gradle 8, so maybe you're using a plugin or something else which is not (yet) compatible with Gradle 8.

Comment: And the full exception stacktrace?

Comment: It is in cipher form because I have enabled R8. Although I'll share it

Comment: Add it to the question itself, not in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing this issue because of the **Parcelize plugin**. I'm using the Parcelize plugin to pass Custom Object ArrayList between activities.

After a lot of trials finally found the solution of changing ***proguard-rules.pro*** files.

Here is my content of ***proguard-rules.pro*** file

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

-dontwarn rx.**

-dontwarn okio.**

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }

-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*


-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

# A resource is loaded with a relative path so the package of this class must be preserved.
-adaptresourcefilenames okhttp3/internal/publicsuffix/PublicSuffixDatabase.gz

# Animal Sniffer compileOnly dependency to ensure APIs are compatible with older versions of Java.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*

# OkHttp platform used only on JVM and when Conscrypt and other security providers are available.
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn org.openjsse.**

-repackageclasses
-ignorewarnings

# Retrofit does reflection on generic parameters. InnerClasses is required to use Signature and
# EnclosingMethod is required to use InnerClasses.
-keepattributes Signature, InnerClasses, EnclosingMethod

# Retrofit does reflection on method and parameter annotations.
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations, RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations

# Keep annotation default values (e.g., retrofit2.http.Field.encoded).
-keepattributes AnnotationDefault

# Retain service method parameters when optimizing.
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}

# Ignore JSR 305 annotations for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

# Guarded by a NoClassDefFoundError try/catch and only used when on the classpath.
-dontwarn kotlin.Unit

# Top-level functions that can only be used by Kotlin.
-dontwarn retrofit2.KotlinExtensions
-dontwarn retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$*

# With R8 full mode, it sees no subtypes of Retrofit interfaces since they are created with a Proxy
# and replaces all potential values with null. Explicitly keeping the interfaces prevents this.
-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* <methods>; }
-keep,allowobfuscation interface <1>

# Keep inherited services.
-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* <methods>; }
-keep,allowobfuscation interface * extends <1>

# Keep generic signature of Call, Response (R8 full mode strips signatures from non-kept items).
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking interface retrofit2.Call
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class retrofit2.Response

# With R8 full mode generic signatures are stripped for classes that are not
# kept. Suspend functions are wrapped in continuations where the type argument
# is used.
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation


# Animal Sniffer compileOnly dependency to ensure APIs are compatible with older versions of Java.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*

#-keep public class com.itextpdf.**
-keep class com.itextpdf.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.itextpdf.*

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** {*;}

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { <fields>; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapter, TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

# Prevent R8 from leaving Data object members always null
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}


-keep class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep public class * implements java.lang.reflect.Type


# Retain generic signatures of TypeToken and its subclasses with R8 version 3.0 and higher.
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**

-keepdirectories src/main/res/font/*



-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-verbose
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# Firebase
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }

# in order to provide the most meaningful crash reports, add the following line:
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
# If you are using custom exceptions, add this line so that custom exception types are skipped during obfuscation:
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception

-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**

# Jackson
-keep @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties class * { *; }
-keep class com.fasterxml.** { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers public final enum com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility {
    public static final com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *;
}

# General
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature,Exceptions,InnerClasses
```

**This code is for parcelize plugin**

```
# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
    -keepclassmembers enum * {
        public static **[] values();
        public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
    }
    
    -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
      public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
    }
    
    -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
        public static <fields>;
    }
```

Comment: adding dontshrink dontobfuscate is not a good idea.

Comment: all your progaurd are ignored by this items :
-dontshrink
-dontobfuscate

Comment: I think the "***.R$*" is not for parcelize plugin. it is for Android R file. Am I true?

Answer (score 18):

I think disabling **R8 fullmode** is the solution till all libraries are updated to Gradle 8 and consider *R8 fullmode* rules.

in **gradle.properties** add below line:

```
android.enableR8.fullMode=false
```

Comment: Yes you can do this as well

Comment: Still get the error: `Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'. A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable`; due to `ERROR: R8: Missing class com.google.errorprone.annotations.DoNotMock (referenced from: autodispose2.ScopeProvider and 1 other context)`

Comment: Solution: R8 8.1.56 and gradle tools 8.2.0-alpha15 and `-dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.**` in the `app/proguard-rules.pro`

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you are using a plugin that is not compatible with Gradle 8.0. If it is not necessary to upgrade to Gradle 8.0 I suggest you downgrade back to 7.4.2 until those plugins will become compatible . Another way would be to check the plugins that would not be compatible and try to replace them when they can be added.

Comment: Solved By Adding Proguard Rules

Comment: @chiragthummar Can you share your complete rules file? Got the same problem

Comment: @MichaelWinkler find it on my original questions I added a solution there. The issue is because of parcelize plugin if you have used it.

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3880

Answer (score 2):

The posted solutions did not work for me after upgrading to AGP 8.0.1. I was still getting a ClassCastException for an interface that Retrofit creates and is provided through a Dagger Module.

I was able to fix the`java.lang.ClassCastException` by using the  `@Keep` annotation. This will tell the compiler to keep the interface in the generated bytecode, even if it is not used anywhere else in your code.

For example:

```
@Keep
interface MyApi {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sometimes there is a problem with @Keep so I have added my own script to skip Required classes from Proguards

Comment: keeping the interface also works for me through proguard-rules.pro `-keep interface company.package.** { *; }`

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issues, after uploading build to play store, Add the below pro guard rule

```
-keepattributes Exceptions

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes Annotation
# OkHttp ProGuard rules
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.Nullable
-dontwarn javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault

#livedata
-keep class * extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel {
<init>();
}
-keep class * extends androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel {
<init>(android.app.Application);
}
-keep class androidx.lifecycle.**{*;}
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking interface retrofit2.Call
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class retrofit2.Response
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
-keep class com.packagename.network.responses.** { <fields>; }
-keep interface com.packagename.** { *; }
```

Replace the packagename with your application packagename.