# R8 full mode throws class cast exception AGP 8.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, retrofit, moshi

I recently upgraded to Android Studio Flamingo and AGP 8.0

My production builds with minfiy and shrinkResources enabled, doesn't allow retrofit to make calls. This is the error thrown.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(HttpServiceMethod.java:46)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:39)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:202)
at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:160)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
at $Proxy11.checkIfEmailExists(Unknown Source)
at com.iku.data.network.service.IkuApiService$DefaultImpls.checkIfEmailExists$default(IkuApiService.kt:123)
at com.iku.auth.data.network.repository.AuthRepositoryImpl$checkEmail$2.invokeSuspend(AuthRepositoryImpl.kt:24)
at com.iku.auth.data.network.repository.AuthRepositoryImpl$checkEmail$2.invoke(AuthRepositoryImpl.kt:0)
at com.iku.auth.data.network.repository.AuthRepositoryImpl$checkEmail$2.invoke(AuthRepositoryImpl.kt:0)
at com.iku.data.network.helper.NetworkHelperKt$safeApiCall$2.invokeSuspend(NetworkHelper.kt:27)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
```

I found this issue on retorfit's github - https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3751.
And have added the new rules has commented here - https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3751#issuecomment-1192043644

```
# Keep generic signature of Call, Response (R8 full mode strips signatures from non-kept items).
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking interface retrofit2.Call
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class retrofit2.Response

# With R8 full mode generic signatures are stripped for classes that are not
# kept. Suspend functions are wrapped in continuations where the type argument
# is used.
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
```

But this doesn't solve the issue. Any help would be apprecaited.

My proguard-rules.pro

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

-keep class  com.iku.community_chat.data.room.entity.** { *; }
-keep class androidx.appcompat.widget.** { *; }
#Jsoup
-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
public *;
}
-keepnames class com.iku.user.profile.data.room.models.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.iku.community_courses.data.room.entity.** { *; }
-keeppackagenames org.jsoup.nodes

# Keep generic signature of Call, Response (R8 full mode strips signatures from non-kept items).
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking interface retrofit2.Call
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class retrofit2.Response

# With R8 full mode generic signatures are stripped for classes that are not
# kept. Suspend functions are wrapped in continuations where the type argument
# is used.
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter
```

The gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"

// Detekt
apply plugin: "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt"

// Apply the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

// Apply the Performance Monitoring plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

// Dokka
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile = rootProject.file("a.jks")
            storePassword System.getenv("SIGNING_STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD")
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.iku"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 77
        versionName "0.3.228"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        if (rootProject.file("local.properties").exists()) {
            properties.load(rootProject.file("local.properties").newDataInputStream())
        }

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += ["room.schemaLocation":
                                      "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }

       
    }

    buildTypes {

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".test"
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
    kapt {
        javacOptions {
            // These options are normally set automatically via the Hilt Gradle plugin, but we
            // set them manually to workaround a bug in the Kotlin 1.5.20
            option("-Adagger.fastInit=ENABLED")
            option("-Adagger.hilt.android.internal.disableAndroidSuperclassValidation=true")
        }
    }
    namespace 'com.iku'
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.6.1"
    def room_version = "2.5.1"
    def camerax_version = '1.3.0-alpha05'
    def work_version = '2.8.1'
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:$camerax_version"

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'

    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-ktx:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-utils-ktx:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:3.0.0'

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:18.3.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.2.1'

    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'

    // Java language implementation
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.6'
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.0"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0"
    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji-appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji-bundled:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.6'
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0"
    implementation 'androidx.dynamicanimation:dynamicanimation:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0"
    implementation("androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0")
    implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'

    // Flexbox
    implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.10'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.4'

    // Third party
    implementation('io.coil-kt:coil:2.2.0')
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:6.0.0'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'nl.dionsegijn:konfetti:1.3.2'
    implementation 'me.saket:better-link-movement-method:2.2.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.14.3'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:5.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.skydoves:balloon:1.5.3'
    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.5.4'

    // Life cycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"

    // Data store
    implementation 'androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0'

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.7'

    //OKHttp Interceptor
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.7'

    // Moshi
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.14.0'
    kapt("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.14.0")

    // Support for Java 8 features
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'

    // Work Manager Kotlin + coroutines
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    // Room Paging 3 Integration
    implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:$room_version"

    // hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.45'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.45'
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0")

    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.7'

    // Testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.5.1'

    //Amplitude
    implementation 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:3.35.1'

    // Firestore
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.4.0')

    //Firebase UI
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:8.0.0'

    //Konfetti UI Github Library
    implementation 'nl.dionsegijn:konfetti:1.3.2'

    // WhatTheStack
    debugImplementation 'com.github.haroldadmin:WhatTheStack:1.0.0-alpha04'


}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Hi @Abhishek You can find it here.

Answer (score 7):

New proguard rules added but not published yet, you can add these rules to your proguard-rules files.

```
 -keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking interface retrofit2.Call 
 -keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class retrofit2.Response 
 -keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
```

Comment: I have already added these rules as you can read in my question and it doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. I found a solution that works for me. In the kotlin data class, I had some properties without a default value, like:

```
val name: String,
val city: String?,
```

This works without a problem with `fullMode=false`, but with `fullMode=true` I get a ClassCastException on Retrofit download.

Fix:

```
val name: String = "",
val city: String? = null,
```

Unfortunately, I don't understand why this is working.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided the code for your retrofit interface. So I will assume that you have declared some json data classes and use them in return type of your retrofit methods.

According to [R8 FAQ](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/main/compatibility-faq.md#retrofit) the model data classes used as return type need to be kept as well:

example from the link:

```
interface Api {
    @GET("<uri>")
    fun getData(): Observable<Data>
}
```

> Note, the Data class probably also needs to be kept if used since this is also constructed reflectively.

After reading this I added this rule to my proguard file and it worked:

```
-keep class my.app.packagename.api.response.** { <fields>; }
```

Note: **my.app.packagename.api.response** is the folder where I've added all Data classes I use as json models. For example:

```
package imy.app.packagename.api.response

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class AuthLoginJson(

    @SerializedName("access_token") val accessToken: String? = null
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Abhishek I Was facing the same issue while **upgrading** the android gradle plugin version to 8.0

I have solved it by adding some proguard-rules which you can find from

[Upgrading Gradle from 7.4.2 to Gradle 8.0.0 gives error on release app - java.lang.ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76073318/upgrading-gradle-from-7-4-2-to-gradle-8-0-0-gives-error-on-release-app-java-la)

It works for me. **I have explained it fully**.

Answer (score 1):

Use this proguard rule

```
# Retrofit
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }

# OkHttp
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }

# Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

 -keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking interface retrofit2.Call
 -keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class retrofit2.Response
 -keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
```

Comment: worked for me. thanks