R8 Shrinker removes retrofit interfaces
We have multiple interfaces which inherit from another
interface ApiInterface : AuthMobileApiInterface, DashboardApiInterface {

    ...

    @GET("rest/user/context")
    fun getUserContext(): Call<UserContext>

    ...

}

AuthMobileApiInterface and DashboardApiInterface are containing methods with retrofit  annotations as well.
We also have a class DemoApi which implements ApiInterface but as the name suggests is only used while in demo mode.
While upgrading to Gradle 8.4 and AGP 8.3.2 we experienced a ClassCastException ->
retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall cannot be cast to DemoApi.getUserContext.Call.
The cast exception itself makes sense because ExecutorCallbackCall implements Call but our DemoApi only provides a Call implementation.
The thing that makes no sense is that the application used our DemoApi everywhere where we used the ApiInterface instead of the service instances created via retrofit.create().
This happened with minification enabled (release build).
After playing around with ProGuard rules we found out that annotating all involved interfaces with @Keep resolved the issue.
I want to understand R8 and retrofit.
My questions are:

Is this a retrofit bug?
Did we missed something of the retrofit documentation?
Is annotating all interfaces with @Keep a valid solution or did we messed up something?

Any guidance to understand the situation is welcome.
History of Dependency Updates

Update AGP from 7.4.2 to 8.3.2, Gradle 7.5 to 8.4, Java 11 to 17

Resulted in the mentioned issues.


Update retrofit 2.9.0 to 2.11.0

No change. Error is the same.



Facts

Gradle 8.4 (before 7.5)
AGP 8.3.2 (before 7.4.2)
retrofit 2.11.0 (before 2.9.0)
android.enableR8.fullMode=false
isMinifyEnabled = true

working with isMinifyEnabled = false


isShrinkResources = true

References

Upgrading Gradle from 7.4.2 to Gradle 8.0.0 gives error on release app - java.lang.ClassCastException
https://github.com/square/retrofit

https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/trunk/retrofit/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/retrofit2.pro


https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/4134


Issue is related to proguard. Can you post your app gradle and tell are you getting exception in debug or in release build ?

The exception happens with isMinifyEnabled = true. This in enabled in release builds. The debug works as expected.
Do you need anything specific of the app build.gradle file? It's huge and I can't post everything.

You have to write rules for keeping the classes in proguard file.

Regarding their documentation I don't have to:

R8 / ProGuard
If you are using R8 the shrinking and obfuscation rules are included automatically.
ProGuard users must manually add the options from retrofit2.pro. You might also need rules for OkHttp and Okio which are dependencies of this library.

https://github.com/square/retrofit
I tried it anyway but without fixing this issue.

I don't know how you come to the conclusion of not adding it. Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/76328211/24823442 and link of git https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/trunk/retrofit/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/retrofit2.pro

Well their documentation says it quite obviously. I pasted the reference in my previous post. "If you are using R8 the shrinking and obfuscation rules are included automatically.". We are using R8
The whole proguard-rules.pro mentioned in the stackoverflow post just copies the content of the retrofit repo. Which I also tried, as mentioned before. Without success.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

IMHO, I don't think there is a bug in retrofit as they have mentioned to keep classes and interfaces in proguard file.
Check this section in GitHub



As in your code you have mentioned that

android.enableR8.fullMode=false

So in that case users must manually add the options from retrofit2.pro which you did and fixes your issue.
Things to consider :

Your ProGuard configuration appears to become restrictive between Gradle 7.4.2 and Gradle 8.4 now you actually do want this rule in there and that could result in more aggressive obfuscation on their side which is why you are getting exception of expected class name resulting in getting ClassCastException

The behavior of Retrofit has changed between the versions and gradle 7.4.2 and 8.4 require different approaches as Gradle uses newer versions than your current setup for these libraries That library is an older version of the target library and though less likely, a newer one could have used reflection more for call type mapping making it also vulnerable to obfuscation issues.



Debugging Steps:

Compare ProGuard logs:  If you have ProGuard logs from 2 Gradle versions, compare them to see if there's any difference in obfuscation of your API interfaces.

Retrofit Version Testing:  Attempt  to have a controlled experiment using your older version of Retrofit with Gradle 8.4, and see if the exception now occurs within. This may help in showing whether the version of Retrofit is the reason of causing the problem.


By systematically checking them, it should be possible to find the exact reason why the mention of the ClassCastException started to appear with an upgrade of Gradle.

This way, you could pick the right solution from below:

Fine-tune Proguard Rules: If the problem is overly aggressive Proguard rules, tweak them to retain the necessary interface names.
Custom Call Adapter Factory: If this doesn't work out, or you prefer a more fine-grained control over call adapter creation, you can create your own call adapter factory.
Downgrade Gradle: In the case of Gradle, when downgrading it temporarily resolves the issue, you would want to be looking into compatibility issues, or wait for a bug to be fixed with newer versions of Gradle.

Reference links-

https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/trunk?tab=readme-ov-file#r8--proguard

https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#compatibility

https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/release-notes.html

https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin?buildsystem=ndk-build#updating-gradle

https://developer.android.com/build/agp-upgrade-assistant



You are right that this should in principle just work out-of-the-box, since the keep rules of Retrofit are included automatically in your build by AGP. Since you are building with a new version of Retrofit, the issue should not be caused by running with some obsolete rules.
This could either be an issue in the Retrofit keep rules or R8. It is difficult to diagnose this without looking more closely at what goes wrong.
In R8, we have support for generating a zip dump that contains all the inputs that goes into the R8 compilation, including the app's JVM class files, the keep rules, the version of the compiler, etc. See also https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/main/doc/compilerdump.md.
Would it be possible for you to share such a compiler dump privately with christofferqa@google.com and sgjesse@google.com? That way we can reproduce the build and determine whether this is due to inadequate keep rules or a bug in R8.
The file can be generated by running:
./gradlew assembleRelease --no-daemon -Dcom.android.tools.r8.dumpinputtodirectory=/path/to/dumps

The generated file is a zip so you can easily inspect its contents.

Hey Christoffer, I ran ./gradlew assembleDevRelease --no-daemon -Dcom.android.tools.r8.dumpinputtodirectory=/reports and received an error:

Task :app:minifyDevReleaseWithR8 FAILED
ERROR: R8: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /reports/dump9075417633426.zip

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyDevReleaseWithR8'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable
Compilation failed to complete, origin: /reports/dump9075417633426.zip

Any insights?

For clarification: I'm able to build assembleDevRelease without the additional attributes.

Did you create the directory /reports before running the command? It looks like the compilation may be trying to write the zip file but fails due to the directory not existing.

The directory exists. We put other files in there as well. If time fits, I try to figure it out. Any other clues?

I wonder if this could be due to permissions. Can you try using an output dir in the app dir?

I do think this is a bug with the combination of Retrofit 2.11.0, Gradle 8.4 / AGP 8.3.2, and R8, as I have the same versions and I'm seeing the same problem. I, on the other hand, have R8 full mode enabled.
The problem is solved with this rule, which is similar to one that Retrofit2 already has, except that removes allowshrinking:
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}


in your proguard-rule.pro file add the following line
-keepnames class com.google.gson.** {*;}
-keepnames enum com.google.gson.** {*;}


How did you came up with this? It's completely off. We are not using gson at all.
